# pagination not working for category of custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

When I use pagination for custom post type `product` its working fine but its not working for the categories of custom post type. for ex. pagination working for this `http://localhost/wordpress/products/page/2/` and not for this `http://localhost/wordpress/products/landscape/page/2/` its always showing the first page content. How to solve this? given below is my code.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' =>1,'taxonomy' =>'product_cat','term' => $cat_name1,'orderby'=>'post_date','page'=>$paged );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
if($wp_query->have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()): $wp_query->the_post();

<div class="product_list">
<?php the_title();?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $wp_query ) );//plugin code ?>
<?php else : ?>
<!-- No posts found -->
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<?php echo "No Products found for this categoy!." ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

-Replace 'page' arguments with 'paged'

-Replace 'taxonomy' with 'tax_query'.

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');  
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$taxonomy_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'fields' => 'ids'
) );


$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' =>1,'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $taxonomy_terms,
        ),
    ),'orderby'=>'post_date','paged'=>$paged );
```

In your question, you have used `$cat_name1` for terms listing then please use following code:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');  
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' =>1,'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cat_name1,
        ),
    ),'orderby'=>'post_date','paged'=>$paged );
```

**Pagination :**

please replace `wp_pagenavi()` function with following code:

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '/page/%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, $paged ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
```

Comment: @ vrajesh hi i tried with 'tax_query' but still not showing next page content. Pagination showing next page link but not getting next page content.

Comment: actually `$cat_name1 ='landscape'` its not id

Comment: if it is slug then you need to change 'field' parameter from 'id' to 'slug'. also make sure you have saved enough posts to that terms :)

Comment: the term 'landscape' has 2 posts.

Comment: where did you add your code ? in template file or other files? @Amith

Comment: its a custom template. @vrajesh

Comment: @amith which posts are listed in page 2 ?  is page2 show first page posts?

Comment: @Amith okay, means your page parameter not working. I have added two if condition to get variable $paged(see answer). print or echo $paged. what do you get value of $paged variable in page no.2?

Comment: oh no its again the same result. If i give `$paged =2` manually its showing next page content. So now I thinks that its better to get the url and explode the `page` from url to get page parameter.

Comment: @Amith rename $wp_query to $custom_query . http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176506/accessing-the-post-content-with-wp-query

Comment: Thanks for your help. But still i don't know why its not working?.

Comment: so i made some changes like this and its working fine now. `$link = explode('/page/',$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
 $link = explode('/',end($link));
 $paged = $link[0];`